# HTTP 500 error while trying to POST using C# to OracleDB without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, http, post, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I am trying to POST data to Oracle db without using Entity Framework or Procedures. But I keep getting HTTP 500 while trying to access it using Fiddler or Mobile app. Below is the code I am trying but I am not sure whether this is the way it will be done. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("InsertData")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(DataClass DataClass)
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ConnString");

    using (var conn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        string InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO OracleTable (DATA_ID1,DATA_ID2,DATA_ID3)" +
                                "Values (@DATA_ID1,@DATA_ID2,@DATA_ID3)";

        cmd.CommandText = InsertCommand;
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@DATA_ID1", DataClass.DATA_ID1));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@DATA_ID2", DataClass.DATA_ID2));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("@DATA_ID_3", DataClass.DATA_ID_3));


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Comment: Can you post a stack trace and exception details? It's hard to say what's wrong without any evidence.

Comment: Just like @Elliveny wrote, we need exception details. However, I'm not sure whether explicit call for conn.Close() is necessery. You have using statement for that.

Comment: Your sql query string has parameter Data_ID3 but you are adding Data_ID_2 to the collection.